# How can I compress an image with an external src?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a "dynamic seal" (an inline html anchor,image,and scriptblock) that is required by my client. It works as intended (in fact I am required to post it as-is).  However, [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) has identified image compression that still needs to be done. I know it's not critical and merely a suggestion, but it raises the question of how I can compress an image that is loaded from an external website in the `<img src="...">` tag.

For better context, here is the html block in question.

```
<a id="bbblink" class="ruhzbum" href="http://www.bbb.org/tucson/business-reviews/wheel-chair-lifts-and-ramps/special-needs-vehicles-in-tucson-az-20000108#bbbseal" title="Special Needs Vehicles, Wheel Chair Lifts &amp; Ramps, Tucson, AZ" style="display: block; position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 150px; height: 68px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
   <img style="padding: 0px; border: none;" id="bbblinkimg" src="http://seal-tucson.bbb.org/logo/ruhzbum/special-needs-vehicles-20000108.png" width="300" height="68" alt="Special Needs Vehicles, Wheel Chair Lifts & Ramps, Tucson, AZ" />
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">var bbbprotocol = "https:" ==
   document.location.protocol ? "https://" : "http://";
   document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + bbbprotocol +
      "seal-tucson.bbb.org" + 
      unescape("%2Flogo%2Fspecial-needs-vehicles-20000108.js") + 
      "' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
 </script>
```

I have been able to compress all the images that are on my server, but how can I compress an image like this?

I have done an hour of Internet searches but have not been able to find any useful approaches. Perhaps because I did not use the correct keywords?

Is there a way do compress the image so that Google PageSpeed is happy?

Comment: Why dont you you download the image to your server, compress it and serve it from there?

Comment: Because it's not a static image. It's a dynamic image that can be subject to change, depending on the client's current rating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. 
You are trying to solve a "problem" that is not your problem.

Google page insights (and most page speed analyzers), pre-suppose the best possible scenario - which most of the time is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  The download of that image is a connection between the user's browser and the `seal-tucson.bbb.org` server that hosts the image.  Your own server isn't involved; the download is out of your control.  It's up to the BBB to compress the image they host on their server.

(You could put a compressed copy of the image on your own server and change the script to refer to your own copy instead of the original, but it sounds like you're not permitted to use the seal that way.)

Comment: That is correct. I am required to use the seal as-is. It must be all inline. When I tried tweaking it, it caused rendering issues.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very old question but actually it is possible by now without downloading the original image with free and open source image resize services like weserv.nl (https://github.com/weserv/images).

**original:**

- size: 525 B
- first load time: ~650 ms
- load time: ~60 ms
- url: http://seal-tucson.bbb.org/logo/ruhzbum/special-needs-vehicles-20000108.png

**resized (on quality=60):**

- size: 233 B
- first load time: ~900 ms
- load time: ~60 ms
- url: https://images.weserv.nl/?url=http://seal-tucson.bbb.org/logo/ruhzbum/special-needs-vehicles-20000108.png&q=60

First load is slightly slower for the resized one, but after that it is the same (around 60ms).

With JavaScript you can wrap all of your images dynamically, e.g.:

```
const resizeExternalImage = ImgtoBeResized => {
  return `https://images.weserv.nl/?url=${ImgtoBeResized}&q=60`
}
```

For smaller projects the free service can be an option (I am using it in my React.js apps), for bigger ones/huge amount of images: you may need a service with a guaranteed uptime.